# How to send audio wav file generated at the server to client browser?

Tags: python, html, web, flask

I'm using flask for my application. I would like to send an audio wav file from the server side to client with or without saving the wav file on the disk.

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an in-memory file with [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from flask import make_response

from somewhere import generate_wav_file  # TODO your code here

@app.route('/path')
def view_method():

    buf = StringIO()

    # generate_wav_file should take a file as parameter and write a wav in it
    generate_wav_file(buf) 

    response = make_response(buf.getvalue())
    buf.close()
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'audio/wav'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sound.wav'
    return response
```

If you have file on disk:

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/path')
def view_method():
     path_to_file = "/test.wav"

     return send_file(
         path_to_file, 
         mimetype="audio/wav", 
         as_attachment=True, 
         attachment_filename="test.wav")
```

Comment: Please tell how pass the wav file to your code?

Comment: Instead of saving the file on disk, you save it to `buf`

Comment: lets say i have the file in my disk and i want to send it to client side then where i need to mention the wav file path name.

Comment: I thought you wanted to generate a wav and send it without saving it to disk.

Comment: Ya that fine! but can we read a existing file in the disk and send it to client browser

Comment: then you can use `send_file` http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: Thanks, the method you have suggested is working. But on client side it is prompting to save or open the audio file. I want to play this audio file in the client browser itself. Please tell how to solve this.

Comment: For a sample implementation on how to use this on the client-side with flask, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67388580/12257758