# how to play uploaded audio file in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to play uploaded wav file on my flask app. I want to add a play button so that user could play whatever he has uploaded.
I have below code to upload file but can't figure out how to play it after upload.

```
@app.route('/')
def upload_file():             
    ''' renders upload page to upload audiofile '''
    return render_template(UPLOAD)
```

index.html

```
<audio controls preload="auto"><source src ="{{url_for('upload_file')}}" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

I am using html and css for frontend page.

Comment: `send_from_directory()` downloads the file, not uploads.

Comment: @bereal I have changed the code as above however, the play button is disabled. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: `source` should point at the download endpoint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365289/how-to-send-audio-wav-file-generated-at-the-server-to-client-browser

Comment: @ammaraslam thanks for your suggestions. I am saving the file to local drive which is successful. but I'm unable to retrieve for playing. Could you please suggest on html code?

Comment: The flask url needs to display the file data, so that it can be streamed through html. The link I commented shows exactly how to do that. If you want to avoid that, you might want to keep the audio files in static folder instead where it would be accessible as a static file