# Python: How to send sounddevice microphone input to flask

Tags: python, flask, python-sounddevice

I want to create Flask Web Application that can hear sound from Server Microphone and download the last sound by clicking button.

For now, I can read and get sound level and recording the sound using this script

```
import os, sys, queue, tempfile

import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np

print("sd.query_devices()")
print(sd.query_devices())

q = queue.Queue()
sd_level = 0

def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(indata.copy())

try:
    device_info = sd.query_devices(None, 'input')
    samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])
    filename = tempfile.mktemp(prefix='test_mic_recorder_',
                                suffix='.wav', dir='')

    with sf.SoundFile(filename, mode='x', samplerate=samplerate,
                      channels=1, subtype=None) as file:
        with sd.InputStream(samplerate=samplerate, device=None,
                            channels=1, callback=callback):
            while True:
                data_sound = q.get()
                sd_level = np.linalg.norm(data_sound)*100
                print ("|" * int(sd_level))
                file.write(data_sound)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nRecording finished: ' + repr(filename))
```

is anyone know how to send microphone sound over Python-Flask ??

Comment: Have you seen this post [Playing a wavefile from the html using flask framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359741/playing-a-wavefile-from-the-html-using-flask-framework)

Comment: I want to stream my server microphone over flask web